# How to add borders with shaded environment (from the framed package)

Tags: framed, border, colorbox

I defined a shaded environement using the framed package (`\usepackage{framed}`) and I would like to add borders to the shaded area, how could I do it?

For instance, how could I add borders in this example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\begin{document}
\begin{shaded*}
    Let me have a background :(
\end{shaded*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\renewenvironment`, in order to replace `\colorbox` with `\fcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{Pink!50}
\colorlet{framecolor}{IndianRed}
\renewenvironment{shaded*}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{\setlength{\FrameRule}{2pt}\fboxsep=\FrameSep \fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}%
  \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document}

\begin{shaded*}
    Let me have a background :(
\end{shaded*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

With `tcolorbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback  = red,sharp corners}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
    Let me have a background :(
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for a solution with shaded, but it may be impossible

Comment: As far as I can tell from the documentation, `framed` does not offer an option to add a frame and a background color.